# ActiveReports Viewer: Fit Page Width prevents Continuous View

Tags: report, viewer, activereports

I'm using ActiveReports 10. If I programmatically set the view type of my `GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer.Win.Viewer` using `Viewer.ViewType = ViewType.Continuous`, it resets the `Zoom` property to the default value. Similarly, if I set the `Viewer.Zoom = -1`, this resets the `ViewType`.

The problem is not only programmatic. While viewing a report, I can click the "Fit Width" button while in continuous viewing, and it changes the view type to single-page viewing, and vice versa.

Is there a way to have fit-width AND continuous viewing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to set both the properties ViewType as Continuous and Zoom as (-1) FitPageWidth. We are forwarding the issue to the development team for further investigation.

However, you can accomplish your requirements by setting the ZoomLevel as that of the PageWidth (for example-148% or 1.48f) in a Section report with default PageSize. It will zoom the document to Page Width and along with it Continuous ViewType can be set. Suggested code:

```
viewer1.ViewType = GrapeCity.Viewer.Common.Model.ViewType.Continuous;
viewer1.Zoom = 1.48f;
```